# UITableView - Cell is nil not called when ReloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using Custom Cell class to draw cell's on **UITableView**. When i first Load the data, **cell == nil** is called

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ZACustomCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

But second time i reload data the control never goes inside **cell == nil**.

I tried setting the datasource i.e. dictionary to nil and reload with no success. What i have to do to reload cells from scratch?

Comment: Where is this code excerpt?  What method?  Are you using the longwinded but intentionally named `dequeue**ReusableCell**WithIdentifier?`

Comment: Why do you expect `cell` to be `nil` after a call to `reloadData`? Cells get reused. Once the table has a screen full of cells, `cell` generally won't be `nil` again.

Comment: you have only cell reload or table?

Comment: reloading full table from different datasource and want the table cell to be nil again

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ZACustomCellTableViewCell";

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil)

   {

      cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ZACustomCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    }

    cell.labelForServiceProviderName.text = [arrayForServiceProvider objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   return cell;
}
```